# Confirmation alert after sending mail php form

Tags: php, forms, alert, contacts

```
<?php

//PHPMailer first part of the code

try {
   
//PHPMailer second part of the code

    $mail->send();
    
    header('Location: contacto.php');

    $message = "Mail sent";

    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";

} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Error al enviar: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
    
    header('Location: contacto.php');

    $message1 = "Mail not sent";

    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message1');</script>";
}
```

How could I display an alert box after sending a mail from my phpmailer form contact? My alert just works without the redirection header. If I set the header (to redirect the user to the contact page) my alert doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The header location statement simply redirects you to the page you want, hence effectively terminates the current PHP scrips and so the alert statements will not be triggered.

One of the ways is to trigger the alert , and then perform the redirection (both by JS)

So the code can be:

```
<?php

//PHPMailer first part of the code

try {
   
//PHPMailer second part of the code

    $mail->send();
    
//    header('Location: contacto.php');

    $message = "Mail sent";

    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
    echo "<script>window.location.href='contacto.php';</script>";

} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Error al enviar: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
    
//    header('Location: contacto.php');

    $message1 = "Mail not sent";

    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message1');</script>";
    echo "<script>window.location.href='contacto.php';</script>";

}
```